# Does a running jump have the move trait?

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e, actions

I see two actions that represent a running jump: [High Jump](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=36) and [Long Jump](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=37). Each of them are made of a Stride action, an Athletics skill check, and a Leap action that is modified by the result of the skill check.

It seems strange to me that they don't have the [Move](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=114) trait, which they would if done as separate actions without using Athletics. I don't know if I'm reading this correctly, for example, this seems to indicate that a fighter's [AoO](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=145) doesn't trigger if you do a Long Jump.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both the Stride and Leap performed through the High Jump/Long Jump have the Move trait.

Taking the High Jump action causes the character to take both a Stride action and a Leap action, which both have the Move trait, and can potentially trigger an AOO.

Consider other actions, such as Flurry of Blows. Flurry of Blows itself does not have the Attack trait, however the wording of the action itself implies as multiple attack penalty is suffered. This is because the Flurry of Blows actions performs Strikes, and those Strikes have the Attack trait.

Comment: https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=387 - here's a link to the subordinate action rules for further clarification, for those curious.