Incapacitation on Sleep Arrow?
The Incapacitation tag is missing from the Sleep Arrow, while it inherits all the other properties from the spell. It does however say that the target of the arrow is "subject to the effects of a sleep spell (DC 17)."
The tags on the Sleep spell are:

Enchantment - Incapacitation - Mental - Sleep

The tags on the Sleep Arrow are:

Consumable - Enchantment - Magical - Mental - Sleep

Does the tag still carry over?

Related question on subordinate actions: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206125/64464 - I don't think this answers this question personally.

I've added some links to Archives of Nethys. Based on what you've cited, this appears to be the Legacy version of rules and not the Remaster.

The tag is on the spell, not the item, so the tag carries over
I performed a search on Archives of Nethys (AoN) with filtering for all consumable items that were Legacy content and had the Incapacitation trait.
Only a handful of items came up and of those, only the Dreaming Round was a type of ammunition. Coincidentally, this ammunition's effect is also to induce unconsciousness. The other items that came up had unique, but debilitating effects to warrant the Incapacitation trait.
I could not locate any specific rules which state that features list all traits that apply, or if additional traits might apply by reference. However, this seems to be the case when reviewing other items which do not carry the Incapacitation trait, but include spells that do have the Incapacitation trait.
For example, the Wand of Paralytic Shock, does not have the Incapacitation trait. However, the purpose of the wand is to allow a once per day casting of the Paralyze spell with some additional damage.

tl;dr: If the item's effect is unique and warrants the Incapacitate trait, then the item will have it. If the item's effect replicates a spell with the Incapacitate trait, then the item won't have it.
